# Negative rates on government bonds

Tags: investing, bonds, interest, rate-of-return

Take the german 10J-Bundesanleihe for example, as far as I know the rates for it went negative recently.

Is there any incentive for private investors / or institutional ones to invest now into this product? Because just keeping your money with yourself, has for my limited knowledge, a better "ROI" then buying it now? Or is it because you are free to trade it, a speculation on the future that the "ROI" indeed will rise (and so the value with it)?

Comment: Bond interest rates can never go negative.  What you saw is redeem value turn negative. An investor that knows how to take advantage of tax deduction incentive will buy this money-losing bond. They are always a rich individual or coporate need such "tools" to lower their tax ceiling.

Comment: @mootmoot: It's true that you never need to pay an annual fee to hold these bonds, instead you pay more up front than you'll get at redemption. But that's got nothing to do with tax deductions.

Comment: @MSalters A bond purchasing cost still a cost. I don't get what you mean "higher up front" when such trade immediately removed a portion of the money invested.

Comment: @mootmoot: "Money immediately removed?" Of course not. If you sell the bond immediately again, you'll see that there is no money "immediately removed". The fact is that the market price of these bonds starts out above the final redemption value, and slowly drifts downwards toward expiry date when it is redeemed.

Comment: *If* you thought interest rates were going to go even lower then bonds bought even at negative rates now *could* see an increase in capital value in future.  Depends how low you think rates can go.

Comment: That's true but without knowledge of inner mechanisms and just a rudimentary understanding of the market, isn't there a point where it simply gets unattractive to invest into it? I mean risk / reward ratios etc. If even US-Bonds pay a positive percentage for even shorter time frames I don't think many people would like to invest into it if the rates are getting lower and lower...

Comment: @mootmoot , I also like your point. Are their tax incentives of the government for people holding bonds?

Comment: It is not the interest rate that turned negative it is the yield.  The rate is 0.25%.  So you will get interest on your capital.  When you sell the bond, you might sell for a price lower than you bought it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly *how* would you keep the money for yourself? In actual, physical cash? That has a non-trivial risk of being stolen.

For many private investors, the better option is to keep the money in a bank account. That just costs a small amount in fees. But with the current interest rates, don't expect to receive much if any interest. And this is likely not an option if you want to deposit several million euros.

Institutional investors may even be obliged to keep a fraction of their investments in the lowest risk category, and German *bunds* are definitely in that category. That's why the Germans can afford such negative rates, they have a captive audience.

Comment: A rate of -0.021 is not cheap "parking" either.

Comment: It's unclear to me why you think you can't deposit several million euros into a bank account. You may be correct, but I'm not aware of any reason why you couldn't.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton: Mostly because the bank has to pay for the necessary reserves, and it's not going to earn much interest from loaning it to others. Of course, _for a fee_, it can be arranged. And if you're an active customer and they're earning money from you in other ways, it won't be a problem either.

Comment: Good point, I just assumed from my point of view that there is no immanent need to diversify because I simply don't have that much, but not without reason there are a bunch of people whose day to day job is just to manage money. And the risk factor has also to be considered as you mentioned. Thanks even though I can't verify this IS the answer, I guess it comes close to it. I will wait a bit though, to mark it as such, maybe someone else wants to answer also.

Comment: After second though, I agree this is a major way of parking huge funds: the market usually has enough takers to unload the bond to with similar rates.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton  Usually a big investor with a huge sum of money will rather arrange with the broker to park their funds in bonds with very low rates, rather than cash out that will require them to pay a big sum as clearing fees and duty.